# Why acessing directly from Service works but not with referenced objects in my Angular application?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a AuthService class that has a simple BehaviorSubject, this is the start from my service:

```
  private currentUserSubject: BehaviorSubject<UserModel> = new BehaviorSubject<UserModel>(undefined as any);

  get currentUserValue(): UserModel {
    return this.currentUserSubject.value;
  }

  set currentUserValue(user: UserModel) {
    this.currentUserSubject.next(user);
  }
```

And i have a function for testing

```
  isLogged() {
    return this.currentUserSubject.asObservable();
  }
```

In a simple component that i have i make this:

isLoggedIn$!: Observable;

```
  constructor(
    public authService: AuthService,
    private _bottomSheet: MatBottomSheet,
    private modalService: NgbModal
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.isLoggedIn$ = this.authService.isLogged();
  }
```

And this is my front end from that component:

This works fine when i update this Behavior:

```
<div *ngIf="this.authService.isLogged() | async as _user; else noUser">
  <ng-container *ngIf="_user">
    <div> {{ _user.name }}</div>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

This don't:

```
<div *ngIf="this.isLoggedIn$ | async as _user; else noUser">
  <ng-container *ngIf="_user">
    <div> {{ _user.name }}</div>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

Why?

Comment: Why have double ngIf? why do you have a div with the first ngif, that one should be ng-container. Remove the 2nd ngIf. your 1rst ngIf is already checking if it is valid or not

Comment: Also, you shouldn't use your service as public, Dependency Injection is meant to be private, your template HTML shouldn't be aware of any DI.

Comment: @Andres2142 the double *ngIf it is a example using one and using another

Answer (score 0):

this is normal because isLoggedIn$ contains only the initial value of the observable (isLogged ())

Comment: I think you don't understand my question.

Comment: I understand your question in the case of updating behaviorsubject your observable will not be syncronized (because it contains the initial state of the isLogged observable)

Answer (score 0):

I have created a stackblitz demo to try reproducing this issue and it works for me. You might have some other side-effect or typo in your app. Give it a try and check out if it works or missing anything from your code here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stackoverflow-bs-no-issue?file=src/app/app.component.ts

I am going to share some tips with you about your code:

- You don't need to use `this` in the template
- Service should be private (maybe you know it and did it just for the demo's sake)
- You don't need the extra ng-container -> ngIf inside the div, because the div already has the ngif condition.